# Angular CLI, can we view transpiled JavaScript files?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the latest Angular CLI, v1.0 Release Candidate. The `ng build` and `ng serve` work perfect (even hitting breakpoints in VSCode IDE ). TypeScript files are transpiled, bundled, and sourceMaps added.

What I would like to see are the .js files that were compiled from the .ts classes. This would happen automatically in my previous environments, as the tsc would convert the files before they were bundled. Is it possible to have the individual .js files output with the CLI? Maybe there is a flag or script that can be added in package.json?

Answer (score 0):

you should find the js files under (your application folder)/app/js or (your application folder)/app/

Comment: not sure :( , i just made some googling and i didn't find much, you may wanna look in your root folder by searching for *.js

Comment: The transpiled .js files are not emmitted by default, looking for a build flag or change to emit them